# Using Node and Express, How to Call remote API from inside server.get(..)

Tags: node.js, express

Because of CORS problems, I want to call an external REST API from inside my node express server.  That is, I have code like this that obviously does not work because it does not return.

How can I make this work and return the results of my external call?

```
const server = express();
server.put('/callme',(req,res) => {
      axios
        ('http://weather.com/restapi', 'put', { zip: 10530 })
        .then((resp: any) => {
            console.log(' success' + resp.data);
        })
        .catch(function(error: any) {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
}
```

Comment: You may need this `res.send(resp.data)` in the `.then()` to send the response back

Comment: Try that and let us know if that works

Comment: what is the 'put' do you try to do PUT or GET request?

Comment: I actually meant axios.put (not axios.get).

Comment: when I change to res.send(..), the request seems to never return (pending in chrome network tab)

Comment: I'm thinking there needs to be a stream someplace.

Answer (score 0):

Axios returns a `Promise` which is resolved in the `.then()`. In order to get the response data back to the client you need to return it with `res.send()`.

```
const server = express();
server.get('/callme', (req, res) => {
  axios
    .get('http://weather.com/restapi?zip=10530')
    .then((resp: any) => {
      res.send(resp.data);
    })
    .catch(function(error: any) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
}
```

It would be a good idea to cache the weather API response for a period of time and serve the cached response for subsequent requests.